# Run 2 Mac Mini's in a cluster and control them as one

Tags: server, mac, cluster

I have 2 Mac Mini's from Late 2012 laying around and I wanna turn them into a cluster. Is this possible? If so, what do I need to do? I also would like to control them as one. I've read about a single system image (SSI) but I'm not sure what it exactly is and how I could set it up. Also, it's just for playing and trying stuff out, would love to get it working.

Thanks!

Comment: bump... sorry, I really want an answer :-)

Comment: You will probably not get an good answer. Clusters are possible, but they have severe limitations. For instance network bandwidth is extremely low compared to memory bandwidth, so memory access is expensive. Also cluster is not a general purpose thing. There's different kinds of clusters for different applications - for instance a load balancing cluster for a web server, where each node is independent. Or calculation cluster. Or database cluster. Or compilation cluster...